# configure log4j with custom level of verbose

Tags: java, log4j

I want to configure my log4j.xml with custom level of verbose - say 350 - in order to print up to some verbose level and including new prints of telemetry that will be at this new level - 350.
What is wrong/missing in my file?

```
<!--print logs of telemetry, warning and above -->      
<CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="telemetryLevel" intLevel="350"/> 
</CustomLevels>

<Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>


    <RollingFile name="deviceTelemetry" fileName="/home/device/telemetry-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="false"
        filepattern="/home/device/telemetry-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10M"/> 
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    </RollingFile>


</Appenders>

<Loggers>   

    <Logger name="deviceTelemetry" level="telemetryLevel">
        <AppenderRef ref="deviceTelemetry"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="trace"/>
    </Root>

</Loggers>
```

this way i get the logger in code:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("deviceTelemetry");
```

i don't know yet how to call the logger to append a message. there is a method log(Level level, String message) which gets a level so it might work - i cannot check it yet.

Comment: What are you trying to log that isn't as you expect(show us how you get the logger and the log statement). Please note that your custom level is in between WARN and INFO.

Comment: Thanks, this is the level i want. please see update section in the main post